# macOS X Mojave - Light and Dark appearance mode toggles

Tags: macos, appearance

Has anyone found a way to toggle between the Light and Dark appearance modes using macOS X Mojave- with a keyboard shortcut or terminal command?

Answer (score 8):

From Terminal.app, you can run (or save as a script):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell appearance preferences to set dark mode to not dark mode'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a quick automator like this:
https://appleinsider.com/articles/18/06/14/how-to-toggle-dark-mode-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-or-the-touch-bar

(You could perhaps use the commands in that AppleScript ato figure out a command line version...)